# Linux. munlockall() in kernel source code

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

Where can I find the implementation of munlockall? It's defined in  "sys/mman.h", but I can't find out where it's implemented....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's in mm/mlock.c: http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git;a=blob;f=mm/mlock.c;hb=HEAD#l368.

You can find things in the kernel source code by grepping the local tree if you have checked it out of git or by using the commit search on kernel.org (top right of the tree pages).

Comment: SYSCALL_DEFINE0(munlockall)
 576 {
 577         int ret;
 578 
 579         down_write(&current->mm->mmap_sem);
 580         ret = do_mlockall(0);
 581         up_write(&current->mm->mmap_sem);
 582         return ret;
 583 }I've got it. Thank you!